# How to create programmatically ubercart orders with attributes

Tags: ubercart

How to create programmatically ubercart 3 orders with attributes and credit card payment information? I want to create custom ubercart 3 orders with products attributes and I am using authorized.net payment gateway in credit card then I want to this payment gateway use for programmatically ubercart 3 order creationg.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try for this? Please share your code also.

Comment: I am facing problem in attributes and credit card payment. Order is creating but without attribute and credit card payment information.

Comment: attributes of the product?

Comment: textfield and select box (2 attributes) and one is required attribute for select by user

Comment: attribute is related to product, not order.